# Why am I getting the attribute error: 'time.struct_time' object has no attribute 'sleep'?

Tags: python, time, sleep

I'm working on a small program to practice multithreading where I create two timer threads to output the current time. I've made two timer functions to output the current time, both of which I want to wait a certain amount of time before outputting again. I am trying to use time.sleep to do this, but when I run my code, I'm getting an error message saying: AttributeError: 'time.struct_time' object has no attribute 'sleep'. Why am I getting this error? I've used time.sleep before without any issues. Thanks!

```
import time
import threading

#timer function that outputs current time
def timerOne(time, number):
    for n in range(number):
        time.sleep(0.2)
        print(time.asctime(time))

def timerTwo(time, number):
    for n in range(number):
        time.sleep(0.2)
        print(time.asctime(time))

t = time.localtime()
numberOfIterations = 3

t1 = threading.Thread(target=timerOne, args=(t, numberOfIterations))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=timerTwo, args=(t, numberOfIterations))

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
```

Comment: Your import has the same name as the parameter.

Comment: What a dumb mistake,  thank you!

Comment: No problem! Happy coding!